# Read only file-system and repeated fsck across 120 machines

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, ext4, read-only

A little background: I work for a security company that has decided to use Linux due to its stability and customization. These machines are NVRs that my company builds from consumer components. Being that they are recording security footage, uptime and reliability is key - and that is where my problem comes in.

We have ~120 machines deployed that all are uniformly built from the same components and are all cloned from source 2 disks (one 16.04 and one 18.04). Regardless of clone, the FS is Ext4

Across all of these machines, regardless if they are 18.04 or 16.04 (both built separately from the ground up for cloning purposes), we are having issues where the machines are running into some sort of IO error and the root partition is going read only. After a reboot, the machine is dropped into an initramfs prompt where I have to perform a manual fsck. There are a bunch of orphaned Inodes that need fixing and wrong bitmap sizes. After this, there is nothing in lost+found The machine then  functions correctly until it randomly happens again. The time between errors varies from one day to 4 months later. Drives always pass short,long and SMART tests. Everything I can find online says "faulty drive, bad Sata cable" etc. I have a hard time believing that EVERY Kingston SSD I have is going bad. Especially as all of these drives are 9 months old or less.

Here is an excerpt from syslog from one of the affected machines.

```
May 19 03:54:55   kernel: [43799.504870] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostb
yte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
May 19 03:54:55   kernel: [43799.504877] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00
 0d 05 fa e0 00 00 08 00
May 19 03:54:55   kernel: [43799.504882] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, secto
r 218495712 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
May 19 03:54:55   kernel: [43799.504890] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:3
15: I/O error 10 writing to inode 6815752 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 27311965)
May 19 03:54:55   kernel: [43799.504894] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical bloc
k 27311708
May 19 03:54:55   kernel: [43799.504928] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#28 FAILED Result: hostb
yte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
May 19 03:54:55   kernel: [43799.504931] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#28 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00
 06 ca 5a c0 00 00 40 00
May 19 03:54:55   kernel: [43799.504935] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, secto
r 113924800 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
May 19 03:54:55   kernel: [43799.504954] JBD2: Detected IO errors while flushing file 
data on sdb1-8
May 19 03:54:55   kernel: [43799.505014] Aborting journal on device sdb1-8.
May 19 03:54:55   kernel: [43799.505020] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1) in ext4_reserve_i
node_write:5976: Journal has aborted
May 19 03:54:55   kernel: [43799.506540] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Remounting filesystem read-on
ly
May 19 03:54:55   kernel: [43799.508041] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_journal_che
ck_start:61: Detected aborted journal0
```

I generally understand WHAT is happening here, but there is nothing indicating as to WHY. I get it that Something is causing an IO error, which is causing the journal to abort, which makes FS go RO. It just doesn't make sense that this is happening across all of these different machines. To make this even more fun, I do not have physical access to these machines, as they are at customer sites all across the region. I have to walk someone on-site to do the fsck /dev/sdb1 -y every time.

Hardware:

- [Asrock H370M-ITX/ac](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/H370M-ITXac.pdf) motherboard
- Kingston Q500 120 GB SSD
- WD 6 TB Purple drive
- Intel [Pentium Gold G5400](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/129951/intel-pentium-gold-g5400-processor-4m-cache-3-70-ghz.html)
- Seasonic SSP-300SUB FlexATX PSU
- Crucial 4 GB DDR4-2400 RAM

What I have done since this started:

- Updated Kernel to 5.3 on some machines
- disabled fstrim on some machines
- added noatime to mount options on some machines

Machines with these changes are still exhibiting the issue.

Comment: Do you also have Windows installed? Are these machines CPU or RAM overclocked? Edit your question and show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`. Get a screenshot of the `Disks` app SMART Data window (it may take 2 screenshots to get it all). Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Windows is not installed on any machine. No overclocking. grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog* did not return any results. I also used zcat /var/log/syslog.2 | grep -i FPDMA, as this was the log from the last time the journal aborting happened. Still no output, so there is nothing regarding FPDMA in my logs at all. Here are the screenshots of gnome-disks: https://imgur.com/a/4gsg9lG

Comment: How's the cooling in your systems? One of the temp sensors indicates 208F! If that's the case, you're cooking your SSDs.

Comment: @heynnema  That SMART attribute reads incorrectly across all of the machines. Here is the proof. I have a "tester" machine here on my bench. Here is me touching the drive while the case is open and everything is room temp while the sensor says 210 F https://imgur.com/a/n6TRWqj

Comment: The only 3 things that are suspect are 1) although the cable dressing is nice, you've got both SATA data and power cables tie-wrapped and sitting very close to the SSD, Un-tie-wrap them both and dress the cables away from the SSD, 2) it's hard to tell, but is there empty space under the bottom of the SSD?, 3) are the boxer fans blowing in, or out? You could also check for firmware updates for the SSDs.

Comment: @heynnema I can see why your suggestions would help if there were a heat issue, however as stated in my last comment, there is no heat issue. The attribute is incorrectly reporting.

Comment: @heynnema Let me answer your questions anyway, as I might be overlooking something and I greatly appreciate your time: 

There is empty space beneath the drive, the box fans are exhaust fans.

There is no firmware update for the Q500. First thing I checked.

Comment: The thing with the cabling is interference and RF effecting the SSDs. You need to un-tie-wrap the cables and move them away from the SSD. We want to eliminate physical loops, and proximity.

Comment: @heynnema Do you have a source for RF affecting SSDs? I have never heard of that. Also, we use the same HW config and layout for our Windows machines and have no issues. I am extremely skeptical of this explanation for that reason. What would you have said next WITHOUT the pictures?

Comment: Well, you have ~120 acting up between 1 day and 4 months. A picture is worth a thousand chat words. I have over 50 years experience in hardware repair, and have been the Service Manager for a number of companies to include DEC, Sony, and Apple. So if you'd like to try my advice, please feel free. If you think it's BS, then don't.